# Azure AD B2C: user signup on email invitation and sending out invitation email

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Let me describe this scenario. I am hosting my web APP in Azure. The front end is a react a single page application. The backend is served in Microsoft azure virtual machine.

There are two types of user accounts. Manager account and staff account.

The manager manages his organization. When the manager wants to invite a person (Will Smith) to join his organization as a staff, the manager can send and an email invitation to the target email address, e.g. will_smith@gmail.com.  Will Smith then can check his email and click the invitation link. And then the link will direct him to a web page where he can register the the new staff account. He can only register the new account with the Email address which received this invitation, namely `will_smith@gmail.com`, or he can choose to do OAuth2.0 / OIDC and sign in with the google account.

I think I need to write code for two parts:

- The first part is nodejs code that handles the process when the manager sends out the email invitation.
- The second part is the Azure B2C custom policy `.xml` file. I need to cover the user journey of signing up with invitation email.

While there are lots of documentation for the second part, I am completely clueless on how to do the first part correctly. Also I am completely blank on how the two parts can work together to deliver the full user journey.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have implemented this by having the invitation redemption xml policy call an API to get the invitation details. This allows more extensibility, such as the ability to revoke an invitation.
Sending the invitation ID in a signed JWT discourages brute force attacks.

The B2C Samples has a good implementation of both the API and B2C policy in the [invite](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite) folder. This only uses a JWT with all the claims and not the lookup pattern as I previously mentioned so be wary of personally identifiable information (PII) disclosed since JWT can be easily decoded and viewed.